# Azure funciton consumption plan call to a firewall enabled eventhub with MSI

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Have the azure function to connect to event hub to polll the messages, the azure function runs on a managed identity, the event hub has firewall enabled with 'Allow trusted Microsoft services to bypass this firewall?' checked.

The function is getting error, so seems it is not able to connect to event hub.

Question, what is the 'trusted microsoft services', it seems the azure function with msi are not one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question, what is the 'trusted microsoft services', it seems the azure
> function with msi are not one of them?

This is the trusted services of azure event hub:

[image]

Azure function is not in the list of the trusted services of azure event hub.

This is the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-service-endpoints#trusted-microsoft-services

I can get check the message of the event hub with no problem on my side.

You can try below steps:

1, add function as the OWNER RBAC of your event hub based on MSI:

[image]

2, Create a virtual network on azure, then put the azure function app to the network:

[image]
[image]

After that, add the network to the firewall setting:

[image]

**Or you can add the outbound ip of your function app to the whitelist of your eventhub.(If you can’t find the specific outbound ip, just use my method above. Similar problems can be solved by these two methods.)**

Comment: The consumption plan won’t come with the vpc so I guess there is no way then, thought msi could work..

Comment: @TommyWang You can not get the message from the event grid?

Comment: Not until I whitelist the function ip ranges

Comment: @TommyWang Generally, we often use two methods when encountering connection problems caused by such firewalls. One is to add the service's outbound ip to the access whitelist. The other is to put the function in the virtual network, and then put the virtual network in the access policy.

Comment: @TommyWang Any more problem? If not, can we end this question now?